# Cronbach's $\alpha$ - two instances

Tags: classification

From a survey I have the following data:
44 questions are supposed to measure 11 variables (underlying theory, 4 questions per variable). These 11 variables are supposed to fit into two categories (underlying theory, 5 variables category A, 6 variables category B). I am unsure how to test this. I was advised to use Cronbach's $\alpha$ instead of conducting a factor analysis, I have some doubts though.

Further I may have a situation like this: I use Cronbach's $\alpha$ and find let's say the reliability of the scales is the highest if always 3 questions are used for each of the 11 variables. Out of these 33 questions I create the 11 variables. And now the bit that confuses me (even more): **To determine the reliability of the categorization, shall I test $\alpha$ of the 5/6 variables, or the 15/18 questions? Or would it be the same?**

[image: Model]

I am quite open to other approaches. I was thinking about looking into McDonald's $\omega_{h}$ or other FA approaches.

Comment: How large is your sample size, and have all respondents answered all questions?  Cronbach's alpha will tell you something about the reliability of the survey or the content areas, but not about the relationships between what you are calling variables.  An exploratory factor analysis will also not tell you about the relationship between the factors.  If your sample size is large enough and your theory strong enough you might want to consider a confirmatory factor analysis.

Comment: The sample size is 260. All questionnaires are completely answered. is the hierarchical omega a viable option?

Comment: no, I don't think so.  Cronbach's alpha and the omega estimate will only give you an estimate of the internal consistency of the survey (kind of an average inter-item correlation). At this point most people would perform a PCA to determine if they have a unidimensional construct or not. They may also perform an EFA to determine if the variable load on the expected factors.  Then a CFA to establish the relationship between the factors.  However.... I don't think your sample size is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I will go through the literature of these data reduction methods and find out whether the sample size is adequate or not.

Comment: Try asking in the Structural Equation Modeling group (SEMNet), which specializes in just this sort of thing.  
https://listserv.ua.edu/archives/semnet.html

Comment: Thanks Ray. I have just opened an account at this mailing list of the University of Alabama and will ask my question there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to make a distinction between two concepts here, one is *reliability* and the other is the *internal structure* of your survey (what you refer to as *categorization*). It seems to me that when you talk about "reliability of the categorization", what you actually want to get at is the internal structure of the test. More specifically, you want to know if there are really two factors underlying the 11 scales of your survey. And as far as I am concerned, by far the best way to do this is by doing a confirmatory factor analysis.

In the comments some concerns have been voiced about the sample size. I am not a specialist in this regard and from all that I have read about CFA so far, this is one of the areas that are still a bit mysterious to me. However, a useful ressource that I keep stumbling upon is the [website of David A. Kenny](http://davidakenny.net/cm/fit.htm). He lists a couple of rules of thumb. Ratio of the sample size to number of free parameters in the model should be about 5 to 1, and generally 200 is seen as a goal. Depending on the model that you specify this might work out for you. If it doesn't, conducting two separate analyses for the two categories (or two factors) might help. I would definitely not be as pessimistic about your sample size as the commenters.

As I have said [in response to another one of your questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67381/determining-which-scale-items-to-use-for-further-analysis/67391#67391), Cronbach's $\alpha$ should not be used to assess the internal structure (Sijtsma, 2009). It will be a lower bound to the reliability of your survey, but only when you have a *$\tau$-parallel* measurement model in the sense of Classical Test Theory. This is something you can find out by doing CFA. But I have the feeling that's not what you want, anyway.

References:

<sub>Sijtsma, K. (2009). On the use, the misuse, and the very limited usefulness of Cronbach’s alpha. *Psychometrika*, 74(1), 107-120.</sub>

Comment: Thanks again Jens. I will look into the resources you provided in [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67381/determining-which-scale-items-to-use-for-further-analysis/67391#67391) answer to further understand the theory and application of $\tau$ congeneric models. I will also go back to David A. Kenny's website in order to understand more about CFA. Students should be warned about Cronbach's $\alpha$ and not encouraged to use it in their analysis. But I suppose since most published quantitative articles report $\alpha$, nobody really worries about its misuse too much.

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately there seems to be a discrepancy between advances in psychometrics and their reception by more applied fields. If you are interested you can read [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11336-006-1447-6/fulltext.html). Also, I found a [freely available source for CTT](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/#chapter6) on [this site](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/).